# REST with ruby?

Tags: ruby, rest

Are there good references teaching you how to send PUT/DELETE/POST/GET with ruby?

I have looked at Net::HTTP.

Is this library capable of all four methods? I couldn't find how to send with PUT.

Are there other good libraries for all these four methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to use the [rest client gem](http://github.com/archiloque/rest-client). Then you can do stuff like

```
RestClient.get 'http://example.com/resource', {:params => {:id => 50, 'foo' => 'bar'}}
```

EDIT: changed url to a more up to date one.

Comment: hmm that hasnt been updated in 1 year now. seems that the project is dead.

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely look at [HTTParty](http://httparty.rubyforge.org/). It's an easy to use library to deal with RESTful requests, JSON responses and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all HTTP verbs with `net/http` library. Other libraries are an option as well - HTTParty is nice, and I personally like [`faraday`](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday).

With `net/http`, you could explore verbs doing something like this:

```
require 'net/http'

http = Net::HTTP.new('api.host.ca')

# GET, DELETE
http.get('/path')
http.delete('/path')

# POST, PUT
http.put('/path', body_data)
http.post('/path', body_data)
```

Where `body_data` is whatever you want to send over the wire. Is also worth noting that all four methods can receive a Hash as an optional third parameter with the HTTP Request-Headers;

```
# GET, with Headers
http.get('/path', { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })
```

This is, obviously, the very basic.

Consider playing with [Google APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/explorer) and Ruby to get a hang of it.